# Print a float with precision right justified

Tags: python, string, printing, floating-point

I'm somewhat of a newb to programming with python so please go easy on me. I'm trying to call the string attribute rjust and also specify precision for a floating point. Here's the code and sample output (note the 0.00 is not justified to the right):

```
print '%s: %s %s \tchange: %.2f' % (Instance1.symbol.ljust(5), 
    Instance1.name.ljust(50), Instance1.buyprices.rjust(10), Instance1.val)
```

OUTPUT:

```
AXP  : American Express Company                          55.38  change: -1.15  
AXR  : Amrep Corp.                                       6.540  change: 0.00
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This shows an example of how to format your output with two decimal points using the older `%` formatting method:

```
v1 = 55.39
v2 = -1.15
v3 = 6.54
v4 = 0.00

print '%8.2f   %8.2f' % (v1, v2)
print '%8.2f   %8.2f' % (v3, v4)
```

the corresponding output:

```
   55.39      -1.15
    6.54       0.00
```

Alternatively, you can use the "new and improved" [.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function which will be around for a while and is worth getting to know. The following will generate the same output as above:

```
print '{:8.2f}  {:8.2f}'.format(v1, v2)
print '{:8.2f}  {:8.2f}'.format(v3, v4)
```

Both sets of formatting directives allocate 8 spaces for your number, format it as a float with 2 digits after the decimal point. You'd have to adjust these values to fit your needs.

Using this approach to format your output will be easier I think since `.format()` will give you a *lot* of control over the output (incl. justifying, filling, precision).

Answer (score 2):

Python [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

```py
print(f'{symbol:<5}: {name:<44} {buyprices:>10.2f}  change: {val:>5.2f}')
```

Output:

```py
AXP  : American Express Company                          55.38  change: -1.15
AXR  : Amrep Corp.                                        6.54  change:  0.00
```

How it works:

```
<44 (left justified, 44 places)
>5.2f (right justified, 5 places, 2 decimal places)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured this out right after posting my question of course...

changed to this:

```
    def change_value(self, sym, buy, sell):
        self.sym = sym
        temp = float(buy) - float(sell)
        self.val = "%.2f" % temp
```

and then called `str(Instance1.val).rjust(10)`