# How to force a integer to have a 1 decimal place

Tags: python

i have a list of integers and floats, let's say

```
a = [1,2,3,4.1,5.2]
```

how do I parse them so that they return

```
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.1,5.2]
```

I need them to be one decimal place because this is the way the files are named.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a float with precision right justified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489326/print-a-float-with-precision-right-justified)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489326/print-a-float-with-precision-right-justified This works. Thanks @Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4.1,5.2]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
  a[i] = "{:0.1f}".format(a[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

```python
d = [1, 2, 3, 4.1, 5.2]
x = map(lambda a: '{:.1f}'.format(a), d)
y = [float(z) for z in x]
print(y)
```

This returns `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.1, 5.2]`

References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: Runtime error (ValueErrorException): Precision not allowed in integer format specifier

Traceback:
  line 2, in <lambda$655>, "<string>"
  line 2, in script

this is the error i got

Comment: @WileyNg Might have something to do with what version of python you are using. For now, try replacing line 2 with `x = map(lambda a: '{:.1f}'.format(float(a)), d)`